# UILabel initial text not showing when connecting as a IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilabel

So I have a UILabel connected as an IBOutlet. It's initial text shows up if the label is not connected in IB, but as soon as I do connect it, the initial text doesn't show up until after I have ran my IBAction which changes the text to something else. For example:

I want it to show "Enter total" when the view loads, and after the IBAction runs it will change to a number. I've tried..

```
myLabel.text = @"Enter total";
```

At the Viewdidload method. I've also tried...

```
myLabel.hidden = NO;
```

It is setup in IB with the correct initial title as well. Nothing will show the initial text without disconnecting the IBOutlet in IB. I know I'm missing something...please help!

in my .h

```
IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

In my xib the title for the label is "Enter total"

Comment: I think you added 2 UILabel's in Xib. Please do check once...

Comment: are you using story board or xib? did you use IBOutlet for your label? would be nice to see the full method code as well as there are a few different get about method for solving a issue.

Comment: check that lable is enabled or not and also remove first reference and give again reference fron XIB....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your nib click on label where you want to show text

2) Then click on top bar view in text write your text @"Enter total";

3) compile and run u'll see it as a default text.